# Q:ionic2 start have error

Tags: node.js

when i run ionic start test tabs,npm instanll have problem like this,any help?

> npm install
>   ✖ Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

```
    npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
    npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
    npm ERR! sha1-T2O+sOp19jQCqE4oWn6F3/ui6zY= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-T2O+sOp19jQCqE4oWn6F3/ui6zY= but got sha1-dFJ7pj/QMynsq3vXPRxBzTZdl34=. (630908 bytes)

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/yeezy/.npm/_logs/2017-06-06T02_33_30_452Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you using a stable version of node?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701 Did you check this?

Comment: I just updated my NODE to v8.0.0. But running npm install still get the an error @Boy With Silver Wings

Comment: It is, I try to downgrade my node to a stable version, because I am in China, encountered a network problem, and then have a node-sass can not install  problem, but finally work for me. Thx from china

Comment: First, clear your cache by running **npm cache --force clean**.
Then delete **package-lock.json**  and re-initiate process